# Calling Rectangle.Inflate() when Rectangle is a property

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, rectangles

I have a class with a `Rectangle` property as following:

```
public class Test {
    public Rectangle Rect { set; get; }
}
```

Outside of the class, I am trying to decrease the height of the `Rect` by 20, but I get an error that is not allowed as it's not a variable.

Then I used `TestObj.Rect.Inflate(0,-20);`, I had no error but it has no effect on the height of `Rect` when I run the program.

I can understand for the same reason as above, it shouldn't work, but why I don't receive any error? Is there a general rule for it?

Then what is the best way to decrease the height of `Rect`?

Comment: Can you post more code?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko the return type of Inflate is void

Comment: Post your sub where you try `Rect.Inflate(0,-20);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Rectangle` is a value type, so it will be copied by value. When calling `Inflate` on `Rect` property you're modifying the copy. Not the actual rectangle.

If `Rect` were a field instead of a property it would have worked because accessing a field doesn't need to copy the value.

I mean the following will work

```
public class Test
{
    public Rectangle Rect;
}
```

Given that `Rect` is a property, you need to reassign the computed value to make it work.

Refer [Mutable value types are Evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `Inflate` is it also affects the `Y` coordinate, assuming you purely only want to resize the height then you can just re-create the `Rectangle` with the adjusted height

```
new Rectangle(Test.Rect.Location, new Size(Test.Rect.Width, Test.Rect.Height - 20));
```

Answer (score 1):

Rectangle is a value type. Inflate method returns new instance of Rectangle but not correct current.